# HDRI: Some parts don't get purple

Tags: hdri

When I select a world environment texture and have not yet selected an image, the entire scene becomes purple.

Some parts of my scene however do NOT become purple.
I am afraid I'm doing something wrong, and these parts / material are not affected by HDRI later on.

Can somebody tell me what is happening here?

Here is the [link to the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bieTeq1v5yxaoMXwV1149NOTOykYfA_u/view?usp=sharing).

Thank you!

[image]

Edit:

Here are screenshots of the material:

[image]

Edit 2:

I have made some tests.
I have activated Viewport Shading->Lights -> Scene World, and I have deactivated it.
I have also used different HDRI textures.

I could not come to a conclusion yet...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you enabled _Face Orientation_ in the _Overlays_? Or does any of the materials have emission?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I did that now. I have added a screenshot of it to my post. Why did you ask me about that?

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion to do it, I was asking because the blue and red tint of showing inside and outside face orientations can cause changed coloring on objects. Without knowing what the materials on your object look like and what other settings you have it's all just guesswork what's wrong with your scene.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I have added a screenshot of the blue plastic material now, does this help?

Comment: I think Crantisz may be correct with his answer that the material is just so blue that it still looks blue in the purple environment. However, if you are afraid this material might not be affected by HDRIs, why not simply load some HDRI in the _Environment Texture_ and see if there's an effect? And maybe use a second HDRI to see if there are differences between the material look with one or the other? If so, it's very, very likely that the material indeed is affected and this would have been much easier than asking a question here with screenshots etc.  ;)

Comment: I see that your blue detail shifts in purple a little. So I suppose my answer is correct.

Comment: So, what version are you using now? In the first screenshots it was 3.2.0, in the new ones it's 2.93.1 and I can see you have _Ambient Occlusion_ (which doesn't exist anymore in 3.2.0) with a factor of 1 enabled. This works as if you had a white environment shining onto the objects - that would of course add to the HDRI environment lighting.

Comment: @Crantisz I was expecting the HDRI texture to have huge effect, not just slight shift. Are you sure I'm using HDRI correctly at all?

Comment: Turn off the _Ambient Occlusion_ and check again. Or better upload the file, else we will be discussing each single change forever.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks. I could not upload it to blend-exchange due to file size limit. I have therefore  uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bieTeq1v5yxaoMXwV1149NOTOykYfA_u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I guess it would be enough if we had the scene with your setting and some object which has the material on it and it's always better to include it with your question and no external hosting.

Comment: Empty image is just pink color to warn. Nothing more, no color shifts, no alert sounds. Just color behaves like regular texture

Comment: And this is the video that I try to copy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBkMEcBUaEs

Comment: @Crantisz Well, that was never in question... it was more or less the premise of the question, why some things don't appear purple.

Comment: I actually don't know why you're asking at all. After disabling _Ambient Occlusion_, the light in your scene comes from the environment and an area light "Area.004", so if you turn off the area light, you only have the HDRI lighting the scene. Turn the strength of that to 0, and your object is completely black except for the emissive materials. Everything as expected. You didn't try that in the first place?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you. No, I didn't try that. Somebody else created this file for me, and I'm trying to "improve" it.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite normal. This part has a blue material, which means that depending on material it may reflect only blue and green colors.

For example, in my scene cube has only diffuse component, and sphere has specular component of Principled BSDF:

[image]

As you see without specular, it reflects only color that it has in base color.

If cube is spectral blue or green-blue (no red component) :

[image] or [image]

And the environment is purple (only red and blue components) this leads to:

Red is emitted - zero or small amount of emission is reflected
Blue is emitted - almost 100% of emission is reflected
Green is not emitted - nothing to reflect.

So the result is Blue color

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I thought of that, too... but the preview of the material didn't look that intense blue as it does in the rendered view. Now that I've seen the screenshot of the material (although it is a custom group), it seems to me the light blue color combined with a roughness of 0.333 seems to me even more mismatching that intense darker blue of the render version. However, without having the same material it's hard to say and I guess your answer is simply correct.

Comment: As suggested, I did some tests. I have attached them. I don't understand the results yet. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

Additional lighting in your scene can also affect certain objects not going pink or the HDR effect in render.

[image: Environmental Lighting with Other Lights]